# In app purchase, item registration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, app-store

I've read the documentation and couple of threads and blogs about in app purchase, but can't get clear answer. So i decided to ask here with hope that maybe someone here have come into collision with this. I want to make in app purchase, and the items that are selling there is books.

found this line in the documentation:
"Every product you wish to offer in your store must first be registered with the App Store through iTunes Connect. When you register a product, you provide a name, description, and pricing for your product, as well as other metadata used by the App Store and your application."

So the question here would be: 
Do i have to register all of the books that i would want to sell? And do they all have to have the unique identifier of the in app purchase as a different item. Or maybe i would have to just register books that are with different prices?

I hope that you understood me, because my native language is not English.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every book will need it's own unique identifier. If the same book has multiple versions (different prices for example) then each version will need it's own unique identifier. It should become clear and obvious the strengths and limitations of this approach when you register your first product.

Comment: Thank you very much, i thought so, but had never done an in app purchase, so wanted users with more experience to share their experience on this. Thank you for your help!